# I cant fill an array in C all with 0. Im trying memset and array[]={0};

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

I'm using `memset` to fill an array with all zeros but I think `memset` is not working properly (when I debug it in a compiler it does not fill it with all zeros (IDK WHY?)).

When I use for example `B[n] = { 0 }` I get an error:

```
variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

The code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    int A[m][n];
    int B[n];
    int redici = 0, koloni = 0, vkupno = 0;
    //memset(B, 0, n);
    B[n] = { 0 };
    int popolnetaR[m], popolnetaK[n];
    memset(popolnetaR, 0, m - 1);
    memset(popolnetaK, 0, n - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some explanations:

- `B[n] = { 0 };` is a syntax error
- `int B[n] = { 0 };` is a constraint violation as `B` is a variable length array, and the C Standard specifies that *VLAs cannot have an initializer*.
- `memset(B, 0, n);` only sets `n` bytes to `0`, which does not cover the full range of array `B`. You should instead write:

  ```
  memset(B, 0, sizeof(*B) * n);
  ```

  Or simply:

  ```
  memset(B, 0, sizeof B);
  ```
- the same remark applies to `popolnetaR` and `popolnetaK`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int m, n;

    if (scanf("%d%d", &m, &n) != 0 || m <= 0 || n <= 0)
        return 1;

    int A[m][n];
    int B[n];
    int popolnetaR[m], popolnetaK[n];
    int redici = 0, koloni = 0, vkupno = 0;
    memset(A, 0, size A);
    memset(B, 0, size B);
    memset(popolnetaR, 0, sizeof popolnetaR);
    memset(popolnetaK, 0, sizeof popolnetaK);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that allocating too much space with automatic storage may cause a **stack overflow**, which will happen for moderately large values of `m` and/or `n`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use variable-sized table declaration using `int A[m][n]`, because its behavior is not specified in every situation -- I strongly recommend you reading [this blog post](http://ayekat.ch/blog/vla). In C99 it was allowed, but since C11 it's not a part of the standard, it's an optional feature.

To solve your problem -- memset is taking `Number of bytes to be set to the value.` as the third, `num` argument. So you don't want to use

```
memset(B, 0, n);
```

but

```
memset(B, 0, n * sizeof(int));
```

The error you are getting says basically that this "trick" with `={0}`
works only on constant-sized arrays.

Comment: Re "*because it's not in language standard*", Are you sure about that? The document you linked very clearly says they're part of the C99 standard. /// Speaking of, all it says is that you  might run out of stack space if you over use it. Well, the same thing could be said for function call, especially recursive ones. You don't see us avoiding those, do you? Small VLA aren't bad. But yeah, large ones could give you problems.

Comment: *First of all, don't use variable-sized table declaration using int A[m][n], because it's not in language standard*  Absolutely ***wrong***.  I'll be blunt:  if you can't properly use VLAs, you shouldn't be writing C code anyway.  And how do you plan to dynamically allocate a 2-dimensional array of variable size without VLAs?  (No, an array of pointers to multiple one-dimensional arrays is ***not*** a 2-dimensional array)

Comment: AFAIK no, "alloca() is machine and compiler dependent; its use is discouraged." <- from man alloca. The blog is about possible traps when using VLA in C99.

Comment: I added a small edit to clarify what I meant :)

Comment: This is what that blogger posted: "VLAs mess around with my mental picture of what's happening, because a variable declaration depends on executed code"  That blogger better never use something like `realloc()` then.  And this: "I tend to put all variable declarations at the top of the functions. That may be a relic from the C89 times, but for me, this also makes it easier to comprehend what is happening on the stack;"  Seriously?  That's some sort of *authority* on C?  `for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) ...` makes it ***hard*** for him to "comprehend what is happening on the stack"?

Comment: If half the syntax of a language is beyond your ken, don't blog about how to program in that language.,

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but in C11 it's an optional feature, not a standard, there's a flag __STDC_NO_VLA__ for it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision) <- yep, it was removed from the standard.

Comment: Just use VLAs, it is optional in C11 but is implemented by most compilers, and it is very useful if you use it correctly, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I appreciate a lot!